# Fire notifications once USB device is connected to MAC

Tags: macos, usb

I am very new to Macintosh Application Development. I have a question that, is it possible to open my application when  user connects a USB device to the Macintosh? I am very curious on this. Because I have a device and when I connect it to MAC system I need to open my application installed in the app and get the data from the USB device. Is this possible?

Comment: iTunes does it when an iDevice is connected so there must be an API somewhere. Are you using XCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just a storage device with a mountable file system, use NSWorkspace's NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification/NSWorkspaceWillUnmountNotification/NSWorkspaceDidUnmountNotification notifications to listen for it.

If you're looking for any other type of device, you'll have to dive a lot deeper. Check out the [USB Device Interface Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/USBBook/USBIntro/USBIntro.html).

Comment: If you're waiting for a notification, you may want to make a small daemon for this purpose, which you can add to launchd

Comment: If you are hoping to launch/show a notification, then you need to use a Login items "daemon" not a launchd opened process.